# PHP magic method __toNumber() converting object to number

Tags: php, type-conversion, magic-methods

Is there any way to implement a conversion of an object to a number in PHP?

There is a handy magic functon `__toString()` that can convert an object to string but how about object conversion to a number?

Example utilization:

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    /**
     * @var float
     */
    private $factor;

    public function __construct(float $factor)
    {
        $this->factor = $factor;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo(1.23);
$boo = 2;

$result = $foo*$boo;

//wanted output 2.46
echo $result;
```

that code generates the PHP notice (PHP 7.3)

> Object of class Foo could not be converted to number

the [list of PHP's magic methods](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) does not have any `__toNumber()` method but perhaps there is a workaround to that?
Obviously other than just using getter like:

```
getFactor() : float
{
     return $this->factor;
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Not exactly intuitive, but you could have `__invoke()` just `return $this->factor;` and then call using `$foo()*$boo;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A comment was posted with the solution before I could finish my answer, but using [`__invoke()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke) is the closest you can get:

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    /**
     * @var float
     */
    private $factor;

    public function __construct(float $factor)
    {
        $this->factor = $factor;
    }

    public function __invoke()
    {
        return $this->factor;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo(1.23);
$boo = 2;

$result = $foo() * $boo;

//wanted output 2.46
echo $result;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/9E4e0)

Comment: I posted it as a comment as I just think `$foo()` looks odd.

Comment: It does and there are more intuitive ways of doing this

Answer (score 1):

The other workaround I came up with is:

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    /**
     * @var float
     */
    private $factor;

    public function __construct(float $factor)
    {
        $this->factor = $factor;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->factor;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo(1.23);
$boo = 2;

$result = (string) $foo * $boo;

//wanted output 2.46
echo $result;

echo " ";

//double
echo gettype($result);
```

looks very counter intuitive  to use but produces wanted result.